# session_regenerate_id and database handler

Tags: mysql, session

i am using database handler for my sessions which working fine but now i stack into a problem on authentication.

When user login with username/password i do session_regenerate_id and after that i am trying to select the current session_id.

Here is my code

```
session_regenerate_id();
echo $checkQ=" SELECT * FROM my_sessions WHERE id='".session_id()."'  ";
......
```

but i dont get any results. The session_id is the correct one.

After finish load the page and copy paste the SQL Command to phpMyAdmin i get the results.

I know thats its stupid but the only reason i can think of is that session_regenerate_id() "is too slow" so when i try to read the session_id at next line the session_id has not created in database yet.

Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a while, I hope you have found an answer since this was posted, but I'll add my solution for posterity's sake.

The call to `session_generate_id()` will cause the value of `session_id()` to change:

```
<?php
$before = session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
$after = session_id();
var_dump($before == $after); // outputs false
```

This problem manifested for me because in the session write handler I was doing this (without such bogus method names, of course):

```
<?php
class MySQLHandler
{
    function read($id)
    {
        $row = $this->doSelectSql($id);
        if ($row) {
            $this->foundSessionDuringRead = true;
        }
        // snip
    }

     function write($id, $data)
     {
         if ($this->foundSessionDuringRead) {
             $this->doUpdateSql($id, $data);
         }
         else {
             $this->doInsertSql($id, $data);
         }
     }
}
```

The write() method worked fine if `session_regenerate_id()` was never called. If it was called, however, the $id argument to `write()` is different to the $id passed to `read()`, so the update won't find any records with the new $id because they've never been inserted.

Some people suggest to use MySQL's "REPLACE INTO" syntax, but that deletes and replaces the row, which plays merry havoc if you want to have a creation date column. What I did to fix the problem was to hold on to the session ID that was passed to `read`, then update the session ID in the database during write using the id passed to `read` as the key:

```
<?php
class MySQLHandler
{
    function read($id)
    {
        $row = $this->doSelectSql($id);
        if ($row) {
            $this->rowSessionId = $id;
        }
        // snip
    }

    function write($id, $data)
    {
        if ($this->rowSessionId) {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE session SET session_id=:id, data=:data WHERE session_id=:rowSessionId AND session_name=:sessionName");
            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $stmt->bindValue(':rowSessionId', $this->rowSessionId);
            $stmt->bindValue(':data', $data);
            $stmt->bindValue(':sessionName', $this->sessionName);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else {
            $this->doInsertSql($id, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm having the same problem you are having. It's unclear to me whether this is a PHP (cache) feature or a bug.

The issue is that, when using a custom SessionHandler and calling session_regenerate_id(true), the new session is not created until the script terminates. I have confirmed that by doing the same thing you did: SELECTing the new session id from the database. And the new session is not there. However, after the script finishes, it is.

This is how I fixed it:

```
$old_id = session_id();
// If you SELECT your DB and search for $old_id, it will be there.

session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

$new_id = session_id();
// If you SELECT your DB for either $old_id or $new_id, none will be there.

session_write_close();
session_start();

// If you SELECT your DB for $new_id, it will be there.
```

Therefore the solution (workaround) I came about was to force PHP to write the session. I hope this helps.